# Google Don't index my Folder

Tags: indexing, google-search-console

is there any any to prevent google from indexing my folder? Not "Page" but folder

using htaccess or robot.txt or any other way?

Comment: SEO questions are off-topic for [so]. Ask on [webmasters.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: HTTP has no concept of a "folder".  Do you mean all URLs that start with a specific path?

Comment: not sure but i only want to remove folder url from google index
for example:
www.website.com/myfolder/page.html
and i just want to Not index url of www.website.com/myfolder

Answer (score 0):

add below to your robots.txt file

Disallow: /foldername/

let me know if that helps